# Rails geocoding gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I've used GeoKit and acts_as_geocodable in the past. I like GeoKit, but its missing nicer features like named_scopes.  I'm not a huge fan of acts_as_geocodable because it duplicates address data into its own table.

Lately, these gems seem under-maintained.

What are some actively maintained gems out there?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I maintain the Geocoder gem:

http://rubygems.org/gems/geocoder

Source code:

http://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

I can tell you it's actively maintained because I'm working on Rails 3 compatibility as I write this! It's designed to be very simple, while providing the most commonly-used geocoding features. It provides named scopes and doesn't duplicate any data.

Comment: Hey that looks nice. I'll give it a shot. Just a quick question: how do I circumvent geocoding if the street address is blank?  Does geocoded_by accept an :if option?  Or should I call fetch_coordinates in before_save and put the conditional in there?

Comment: This may be the default behavior in a future version but for now, yes, add an `:if` option to `before_save`.

Comment: That would be a nice feature to have. Thanks for your hard work.

Comment: I was able to implement it easily (only did geocoding, no distance stuff yet) and your code is nice and clean.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! Glad you like it so far. If you install the plugin version (`script/plugin install http://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder.git`) you won't need your `:if` option--it doesn't query Google if the search term (address) is blank. This will be in the next gem release too but that won't be for a few days.

Comment: @Alex does this plugin has the ability to tell a distance between two zip codes?

Answer (score 0):

Plugin version of geocoder is working great for me. Note that you have to rename "scope" to "named_scope" to get it to work in anything less than rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'geokit-rails3' gem can also do geocoding and reverse geocoding:

https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3

It provide multiple geocoders like GoogleGeocoder and YahooGeocoder, So you can choose the most proper one according to your which map you are rendering.